# I need to give permissions to Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have created a new Azure Function and I want to give permissions to an AD User for run it by https. How can I do it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay so you want to allow only a single user to call your function? Check how to enable AAD authentication on the function, and then you have a few choices. You could just check if the objectId in the token matches the user you expect, or you could require user assignment on the app and only assign that user.

Comment: Yes, I only want a single AD user to call the function. To enable AAD authentication the azure function must be running on windows consumption plan? Authentication/Authorization appears grey out because is running on a Linux consumption plan

Answer (score 1):

Follow the article which discuss about how to configure Azure App Service/Azure Function to use Azure Active Directory as an authentication provider.

**[Configure your App Service app to use Azure Active Directory sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)**